# Combinatorics the marriage theorem

Tags: combinatorics

consider a situation of girls and boys in which any set of girls know between them at least that number of boys.Assume also that there are n girls altogether and that each of them knows at least m(<=n) of the boys.Show that the n marriges can be arranged in at least m! ways.

Comment: Do girls have to marry lads they know? :o)

Comment: yes they have to

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove it by induction on $m$. For the induction step take as hypothesis that there are at least $m!$ ways to arrange the marriages when each girl knows at least $m$ boys, and the marriage condition is always satisfied. Suppose now that each girl knows at least $m+1$ boys, and the marriage condition is satisfied. Pick one of the girls, $G$. Marry her to any one of the boys, $B$, whom she knows; this can be done in at least $m+1$ ways. Now remove $G$ and $B$ from the set. Show that the marriage condition still holds, and that each girl still knows at least $m$ boys.